# Is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$. Is $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}$?

My attempt: $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$: Let $x\in U$. Choose $r:=\frac{1}{2}(\text{min}\{x-\lfloor x \rfloor, (\lfloor x \rfloor+1) -x\})$, so $r>0$. Therefore for each $x\in U$ there exist $r>0$ such that $(x-r, x+r)\subset U$.  Hence $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: maybe one more word justifying $r>0$

Comment: @Exodd $r>0$ because $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x \leq \lfloor x \rfloor +1$. Is it correct?

Comment: No, $r>0$ because $\lfloor x \rfloor < x < \lfloor x \rfloor +1$.

Comment: @TonyK Ok sorry my fault, $x$ can not take the integer values. So, $x \neq \lfloor x \rfloor$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:
$\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}=\cup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(n,n+1)=\cdots \cup(-2,-1) \cup (-1,0)\cup (0,1)\cup (1,2)\cup (2,3)\cdots$, is the countable union of open sets, thus is open